# Wordpress Hook Pre Post Update

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I am writing a wordpress plugin. I would like to to set the post status to publish if post status is future.

I know one hook that is to be used that is pre_post_update.

However where is the array of post related details stored so that I can change the post_status?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function that calls the pre_post_update hook appears on line 1525 of wp-includes/posts.php for me:

```
do_action( 'pre_post_update', $post_ID );
```

As you can see, it passes the ID of the post being updated when it is executed. To get the post from there, you would just call `get_post()`, e.g.:

```
function do_something_with_a_post($post_id, $post_data) {
     // now do something with $post_data
}
add_action('pre_post_update', 'do_something_with_a_post', 10, 2);
```

The `$post` variable above should reference an object with all of the various attributes about a post you are looking for, hopefully.

Comment: Modify that `$post` variable doesn't seem to propagate it to the database.

Comment: `pre_post_update` accepts `$data` as a second argument: `do_action( 'pre_post_update', $post_ID, $data );`

Comment: to update the data, use a filter instead of an action. the filter to alter data saved in DB is `wp_insert_post_data`   https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data