# Update a post without update post title

Tags: wordpress, hook, posts

I want to update post data without update post title even if user change the post title.
For this functionality I have write the following codes. But it's not working.
My code is as follows :

```
function update_post_without_update_title($post_id,$data) {
      $post = get_post($post_id);
      if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
         return;
      if ($data['post_status'] == "publish"){
          $data['post_title'] = $post->post_title;
       }
}

add_action('pre_post_update','update_post_without_update_title',10,2);
```

Can you tell me what to fix here ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you need to use do_action( ); check link once  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260210/wordpress-hook-pre-post-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function :

```
 add_action('post_updated','after_update_post_without_update_title',10,3);

 function after_update_post_without_update_title($postId,$after,$before)
 {
        global $wpdb;
        $where = array( 'ID' => $postId );
        $oldTitle = $before->post_title;
        $data = array('post_title'=>$oldTitle);
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, $data, $where );
        return true;
 }
```