# Wordpress hook that fires just before the data is stored to the database

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to intercept the wordpress core "publish submit" form and I have tried few ways of doing it, but unfortunately none of them worked for me.

So, I can't change anything on the frontend since I am developing a plugin that is doing some checkups before the data is stored.

Hooks used:

1. save_post - fires after everything is stored
2. wp_insert_post_data - for some reason doesn't run properly

Any other way?

I have checked other questions on the SO, but none helped me.

Thanks

Comment: _"wp_insert_post_data - for some reason doesn't run properly"_. Perhaps `add_filter( 'wp_insert_post', 'your_custom_function', 10, 3 );`

Comment: @stckvrw going to try it now :D Comming back with the feedback.

Comment: @stckvrw *The wp_insert_post hook is an action in WordPress that is triggered after a post or page is inserted or updated in the database.* I need before :3

Comment: Ok, maybe https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_post_update

Comment: This one is promising. Going to try it now. Would this be valid *add_action('pre_post_update', 'test', 10, 2);* ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress Hook Pre Post Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260210/wordpress-hook-pre-post-update)

Comment: @stckvrw It answered half of it but could you please put it in answer so I can accept it. The part that was not covered is that when the post is updated this hook wont be called so I needed  to call this hook with other one ^^